# Jersey Client API - authentication error using jersey rest api

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I have created one authorization filter before calling rest API but i am getting 404 error message. Below is classes which I have created.

--RestAuthenticationFilter

```
package com.sms.Security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RestAuthenticationFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filter) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            String authCredentials = httpServletRequest
                    .getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER);

            // better injected
            AuthenticationService authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();

            boolean authenticationStatus = authenticationService
                    .authenticate(authCredentials);

            if (authenticationStatus) {
                filter.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                    httpServletResponse
                            .setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

--AuthenticationService

```
package com.sms.Security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class AuthenticationService {


    public boolean authenticate(String authCredentials) {

        if (null == authCredentials)
            return false;
        // header value format will be "Basic encodedstring" for Basic
        // authentication. Example "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
        final String encodedUserPassword = authCredentials.replaceFirst("Basic"
                + " ", "");
        String usernameAndPassword = null;
        try {
            byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(
                    encodedUserPassword);
            usernameAndPassword = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
                usernameAndPassword, ":");
        final String username = tokenizer.nextToken();
        final String password = tokenizer.nextToken();

        // we have fixed the userid and password as admin
        // call some UserService/LDAP here
        boolean authenticationStatus = "admin".equals(username)
                && "admin".equals(password);
        return authenticationStatus;
    }
}
```

--Web.xml file

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sms.presentationT</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
             <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sms.Security.RestAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

--Login API

```
package com.sms.presentationT;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import com.sms.userServices.*;
import com.sms.Registrations.Regitration;
import com.sms.persistenceT.*;
import com.sms.persistenceT.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import com.sms.Security.*;

@Path("/user-servicesLogincheck1")
public class Check implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @POST
    @Path("/LoginPagecheck1")

    //@Consumes("application/json")
    //@Produces("application/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Regitration loginUserInfo(@FormParam("logusertype") String logUserType,
                                 @FormParam("userNAME") String UserNAME,
                                 @FormParam("PassWORD") String PAssWORD) throws ParseException
    {

        System.out.println(logUserType+UserNAME+PAssWORD);

        CustomApplication CA = new CustomApplication();

        CA.getApplication();

        LoginUserServiceCheck LUS = new LoginUserServiceCheck();
        JSONObject jobj2 = new JSONObject();
        jobj2 = LUS.LoginInputDatacheck(logUserType,UserNAME, PAssWORD);

        System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");

        System.out.println("Presentation jobj"+jobj2);


        String jsonText = jobj2.toJSONString();



        System.out.println(jsonText);

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject newJObject = null;

        try {
            newJObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonText);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(LUS.loginresponse);
        //System.out.println(LUS.resultStatus);
        /*
        if(LUS.resultStatus)
        { 
            System.out.println(LUS.loginresponse);


            return LUS.loginresponse;
            //return "UserName is valid";
        }
        else
        {
            return LUS.loginresponse;
        }

        */

        System.out.println(newJObject.get("Name"));
        System.out.println(newJObject.get("Email"));

        Regitration rg = new Regitration();

        rg.setUserType(logUserType);
        rg.setName((String)newJObject.get("Name"));
        rg.setEmail((String)newJObject.get("Email"));
        rg.setUserName((String)newJObject.get("userName"));
        rg.setPassword((String)newJObject.get("password"));
        rg.setConfirmPasssword((String)newJObject.get("password"));
        rg.setBirthDay((String)newJObject.get("birthday"));
        rg.setGender((String)newJObject.get("Gender"));
        rg.setMobileNo((String)newJObject.get("mobileNo"));
        rg.setCurrentAddress((String)newJObject.get("currentAddress"));

        rg.setPermenantAddress((String)newJObject.get("PermenantAddress"));
        rg.setCountry((String)newJObject.get("Country"));
        rg.setState((String)newJObject.get("state"));
        rg.setCity((String)newJObject.get("City"));

        rg.setLandmark((String)newJObject.get("Landmark"));
        rg.setZipCode((String)newJObject.get("ZipCode"));







        return rg;
    }

}
```

-- Error message

```
Mar 27, 2017 1:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2836 ms
Mar 27, 2017 1:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 27, 2017 1:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Mar 27, 2017 1:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter AuthenticationFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sms.Security.RestAuthenticationFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Comment: Looks like your class is not in your war: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sms.Security.RestAuthenticationFilter
`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the RestAuthenticationFilter is not available in the classpath, hence the ClassNotFoundException. Please double check if you are compiling it and putting it in the classpath.

Comment: can you please tell me how add in class path?

Comment: Please see http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2006/06/6-ways-of-setting-java-classpath.html?m=1